# Does the precision of a float change from Python to C?

Tags: python, c, floating-point

I am trying to scale and standardize some data (a subset of the original data):

```
4576, 3687, 3786, 4149
4497, 3707, 3782, 4126
4449, 3712, 3787, 4097
4499, 3679, 3800, 4093
4497, 3660, 3857, 4139
4463, 3691, 3851, 4116
4393, 3712, 3782, 4108
4364, 3765, 3785, 4099
4400, 3846, 3822, 4152
4645, 3905, 3804, 4253
```

These are the mean values of each column ...

```
4400.60009766,  3274.76000977,  3234.88989258,  3402.25000000
```

... and these are the scales:

```
2164.33007812,  2516.58349609,  2280.71508789,  2321.07519531
```

To do the task in Python I use the `fit()` function:

```
data_scaled = std_scale.transform(data)   # std_scale contains the mean and the scale values
```

In C I did the following:

```
void transform(uint16_t* in_data, unsigned size, double* mean, double* scale, double* out_data) {
   unsigned         i, j;

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
          out_data[i][j] = ((double) in_data[i][j] - mean[j]) / scale[j];
      }
   }
}
```

But some of my results differ in the least-significant digits, which seems likely to result from a difference in floating-point precision:

## python result

```
0.08104119   0.16380939   0.24163917   0.32172590
0.04454030   0.17175667   0.23988533   0.31181669
0.02236253   0.17374349   0.24207763   0.29932249   
0.04546437   0.16063046   0.24777760   0.29759914
0.04454030   0.15308055   0.27276975   0.31741756
0.02883105   0.16539884   0.27013901   0.30750835
-0.00351152   0.17374349   0.23988533   0.30406168   
-0.01691059   0.19480379   0.24120072   0.30018416
-0.00027727   0.22699028   0.25742370   0.32301840
0.11292173   0.25043476   0.24953143   0.36653271
```

## C result

```
0.08104120  0.16380938  0.24163917  0.32172590
0.04454030  0.17175667  0.23988534  0.31181670     
0.02236253  0.17374349  0.24207763  0.29932249
0.04546437  0.16063047  0.24777760  0.29759915  
0.04454030  0.15308055  0.27276976  0.31741755
0.02883105  0.16539884  0.27013901  0.30750835
-0.00351152  0.17374349  0.23988534  0.30406167
-0.01691059  0.19480378  0.24120071  0.30018416
-0.00027727  0.22699028  0.25742370  0.32301840
0.11292173  0.25043476  0.24953143  0.36653272
```

The Python code is representing the data as float32. Am I missing something?

Comment: we'd need a [mcve] from the python side, because we don't know which package you're using. numpy uses float32 all right. Bare python uses double.

Comment: Also, what is the precision of your `double` in the C code? Do you know that?

Comment: Try displaying the values with a higher precision - it might just be a display rounding issue.

Comment: Additionally, a `double` in C is (typically) a 64bit floating point type, whereas you claim to use a 32bit floating point type in python.

Comment: If neither of those options applies, it could be an order-of-operations artefact.

Comment: What happens if you change your C code to use a 19 digit precision (.ie.: printf("%.17g", number)). Ditto for however you do that in pyhton.

Comment: The name „float“ is misleading. AFAIK, Python‘s float generally corresponds to an IEEE-754 double precision type, so usually to C‘s double.

Answer (score 2):

If indeed the Python code is performing its calculations in 32-bit floating point, then it is very likely that you are right that there is a difference in precision here.  The C language does not specify the details of floating-point representation, but these days it is rare to encounter an implementation in which `double` does not correspond to IEEE 754 binary double precision format -- a 64-bit format with 53-bit mantissa.

Note also, however, that the differences you are observing are in the 7<sup>th</sup> significant decimal digit.  This is at the very limit of the precision of (32-bit) IEEE 754 binary single-precision format, and perhaps beyond.  You only get 6-7 decimal digits.  A difference at that precision could arise simply from differing order of operations, different timing of rounding, or some similar computational difference.  If indeed you are performing at least one of your computations in that format, then there is no reason to expect the two computations to match to the precision you present.